# Prove double integral inequality

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Prove the following statement:
If $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are integrable over a close region $R$ and $f(x,y)≥g(x,y)$, then:
$$\iint[f(x,y) \ d(x,y)]≥\iint[g(x,y) \ d(x,y)]$$
I am stuck on this question. Thank you in advance

Comment: i hv fix it. Thanks

Comment: Please format your questions with MathJax next time. Go to http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for a tutorial on how to use MathJax ;-)

Comment: @jchau ok. thank you.